# 2012 Infiniti M37X, BCM Reset

Tags: starter, infiniti, bcm

Good Evening,

This has happened twice in the last 4 months, and most recently on Wednesday morning.  When I push the start button, I hear 1 click.  Additionally, both touch entry buttons on the front doors and the touch entry on the trunk do not work.  I know that I can disconnect the negative battery cable for 15 minutes to reset the BCM, however I did not do that 4 months ago.  After letting the car sit for a few days, everything worked correctly.  Should I replace the BCM?  Any guidance would be helpful.  My car has 104k miles on it.

Thank you,
Steve

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!